# how can i use CLIPS source code in my C++ project?

Tags: c++, clips

first,i changed the source code's extension to .cpp. And add them all into my C++ project.

[the source files.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0S5pt.png)

second.im my main func,i code this:

```
namespace ClipsEmbed{
int main(){
Environment *theEnv;
theEnv = CreateEnvironment();
cout << Load(theEnv, "auto.clp");
Reset(theEnv);
Run(theEnv,-1L);
return 0;
}
}
```

after shooting some link and compile erro,it runs ok,but it just a CLIPS IDE,not my program.
just like this:
[the result .jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOlzr.png)

i guess there is another main function,but i did not know where,so please help.how can i use the source code not the DLL in c++ project.

Comment: I added in the `namespace` code that you missed out. Also, you really should include the actual link errors, otherwise we are just poking about in the dark here. And also don't post links to code; post the actual code directly within the question.

Comment: You don't need to change the extensions of the CLIPS source files. Most compilers provide an option for compiling C code as C++ code. For example, in gcc the option "-x c++" will compile the CLIPs source files as C++.

Comment: @GaryRiley there is no link erro finaly,but it just run the main() inside the CLIPS ,not ClipsEmbed::main().And i knew the reason is that there is another main() inside the CLIPS source code,but i just cann't disable it.when i run my project,the source code's main() will be called.so ,my question is ,how to disable it.

Comment: Don't include main.c when you compile the code.

Answer (score 0):

Your explanation is very confused and omitting details, but I think what you need is (at the simplest level):

```
namespace ClipsEmbed{
int main(){
Environment *theEnv;
theEnv = CreateEnvironment();
cout << Load(theEnv, "auto.clp");
Reset(theEnv);
Run(theEnv,-1L);
return 0;
}
}

int main () { return ClipsEmbed::main(); }
```

The `main()` is inside the `ClipsEmbed` namespace, so to satisfy the linker you need a plain `main()` in the global namespace, so the simplest solution is as illustrated, calling the namespace's `main()` from the global `main()`.

---

Following feedback:

```
extern "C" int main () { return ClipsEmbed::main(); }
```

Might help?

Comment: there is no link erro finaly,but it just run the main() inside the CLIPS ,not ClipsEmbed::main().And i knew the reason is  that there is another main() inside the CLIPS source code,but i just cann't disable it.when i run the project,the source code's main() will be called.so ,my question is ,how to disable it.

Comment: What happens if you try `extern "C" int main ()`? That might help override the inbuilt main.

Comment: that will come out an erro "_main already defined in main.obj".and do you know where the other main() in the source code located?maybe that need change the source code.